# Please identify a bike that is like a cross trainer

Tags: identify-this-bike

Yesterday I saw a strange looking bike that I would like to identify. Its features are:

- Stood up riding position with no seat
- Had cross trainer (running machine) pedals
- Handles were similar to those of a child's scooter with a rubber grip
- Located in Bradford, UK

I can't include images as I don't have the rep.

My question is, **what is this type of bike called?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like an Eliptigo, as in  https://gearjunkie.com/elliptigo-stand-racing-bike.  They're intended to duplicate the exercise of running, but without the impacts of hitting the ground.

There isn't really a generic name for them, other than the class of "Funny Bikes" or possibly an "Exercise Bike"

[image]